# Sqlite database not found in file explorer when deploying in Android mobile using eclipse

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using Sqlite database in my Android application. I did not specify any path for the database and I am not using DatabaseHelper class. I am just creating database using queries. It is working fine but I am unable to view the database.

When running with emulator, the database is found in data/data/databases/ in file explorer. I can export it and view using sqlite database browser. But when running with mobile, I cannot find the database anywhere in file explorer. How can I find it?

Below is my coding for creating the database:

`this.db = openOrCreateDatabase("StartPageDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StartPage(STARTPAGEID varchar(100))");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Star(ID varchar(100),VALUE varchar(100))");`

Comment: Run your application via emulator first,then go to check DDMS file,your database is there or not.

Comment: @saravanan yes my database is there in DDMS when run in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not specifying any path for the database then by default it is creating inside the package it self. It is available at `/datadata/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name>` folder, which is viewable only for AVD.

If your database is inside the phone then you can not view it even using the File Explorer of eclipse. If your phone is rooted then you can view it.

Comment: at this location, `/datadata/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name>`

Comment: data/data/ is empty when running with mobile.

Answer (score 0):

What Vigbyor says is correct, but your database will show after the first row insert